# Is there a way to check all merged commits that come from a specific branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

If I have master branch and merge in commits from branch foo multiple times, is there a command to find all those commits?

Comment: You cannot merge the same commit multiple times. Can you draw us a graph to clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry I think my writing isn’t good here. So if I have a master branch and create a feature branch off of master. Now let’s say I make 2 commits on the feature create a merge pull request into master and then merge it into master. Now 1 week later I make another 2 commits on feature then again merge it into master. Is there a way in master to find all those commits that were merged in or all the merged that happened (feature -> master)?

Comment: But you shouldn't do that. Once you have submitted a PR and it is accepted and merged, you must delete that branch. Terrible things will happen if you try to repeatedly merge a long lived feature branch.

Comment: @matt I don't know what terrible things will happen, unless you starting rebasing or amending your history. Merging a branch multiple times is generally not a problem for Git (at least none that I'm aware of) – the DAG takes care of properly resolving such merges.

Comment: @knittl in a collaborative development situation with PRs, it creates unnecessary merge conflicts. You don't reuse feature branches.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the *oldest* merge base of two first-parent histories is an easy enough request,

```
oldestbase=$(
        (git rev-list --first-parent mainline; git rev-list --first-parent feature) \
        | awk 'seen[$0]++ {print;exit}'
)
```

and then your list of `feature` commits to check is

```
git rev-list --first-parent --no-merges $oldestbase..feature
```